# Wifi direct for Google Glass or other options

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass, wifi-direct, google-gdk

I'm trying to create a simple glassware using GDK which wirelessly receives
data from a laptop and uses the data to create some visual representation.

I'm wondering if the current Google Glass supports wifi direct or other kind of 
wifi p2p connection, and it can be used for the idea.

Or is Bluetooth the only available option for this kind of applications?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Glass is basically Android, anything that would work on Android should work with it. I think websockets will do what you want, and there are multiple implementations of that for Android and other platforms.

That said, be sure to remember that Glass is a relatively weak system with a short battery life, so maintaining long lasting communications could be costly. Use caution.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to write some simple network code which simply get a simple webpage, and display in Google glass screen. I tried various codes but nothing works. Can anyone help me or provide some working network code for google glass? or google glass has any limitation regarding network programming? Thanks,